# Grub theme and login graphical user interface

Tags: boot, grub2, themes

I have recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.
Deleting some python2 (pyhton is python2 and lot of dependent packages), makes me that graphical boot menu in grub was changed to other theme.

https://pastebin.com/A68tq3AU ( relevant changes began in line 498 in my opinion)

Dont know its name. I have installed grub-theme-breezer and grub-theme-starfield
New theme:
[image]

Old theme ( something similar to) :
[image]

I want to turn back to default theme and dont know how. I have tried grub-customizer but seems i cant make it to work.

Also i noticed that the boot time, from grub selection menu to login screen, before i had a graphical interface with a background, now i have a console terminal.

eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
but again i didnt make it work.

Summarizing i want to return to theme default or working themes in grub and boot with graphical interface till login screen.

Thanks

Comment: Some details would be helpful. What "other theme'? What packages? The more specific you are, the better chance you have of getting help. Don't reply in comments, edit your question to add info.

Comment: You want to restore what you deleted but you don't remember what you deleted? Did you remove the package in `apt`?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: edited @Nmath, you were correct used apt. I have upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 recently and im doing some housekeeping and cleaning ( ex: delete python2 packages that are going to be deprecated in near future)

Comment: I find it safer to use `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up obsolete packages. If these packages aren't being suggested by this command, that means *something* still uses it as a dependency. My guess is that you've removed too many dependencies that are not yet deprecated and are still required.  My suggestion is to go through the apt logs in `/var/log` and reinstall what you removed.  This might not be a panacea as you mentioned there were whole dependency chains you removed, so that's a lot of variables.

Comment: But i only want to get the default theme of grub in ubuntu 20.04 and also change the booting messages from console to gui ( with a background and animation that ubuntu is loading instead of that ugly console texts)...